# Index was outside the bounds of the array in axWindowsMediaPlayer1

Tags: c#, arrays

I tried to make media player using c# and I have a problem when I want to play next song

"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files = openFileDialog.SafeFileNames;
        path = openFileDialog.FileNames;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wmp.URL = path[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Error `"Index was outside the bounds of the array."` occurred on

```
wmp.URL = path[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wmp.URL = path[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

This is failing because listBox1.SelectedIndex is a number larger than the number of elements in the path array. You are trying to pull an item out of the array that doesn't exist.